# Can't Email Graphs with Graphite

Tags: django, email, smtp, graphite

I'm unable to email rendered graphs using Graphite.  My settings in local_settings.py are:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

I have been able to SMTP email via telnet and through `pyhton manage.py shell` using:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, get_connection  
get_connection()  
>>> django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend object at 0x1bb6310   
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'This is a test', 'user@example.com',['user@example.com'])
email.send(fail_silently=False)  
>>> 1
```

When I try to send a graph from the graphite dashboard, after I fill out the "from", "to", "subject" and "message" fields, I get a message box with a progress bar that says "Please Wait...Processing Request" which disappears in less than a second.  No graph is ever sent.

I am using Graphite 0.9.12 on CentOS 6.5. I downloaded the Graphite RPM along with its dependencies from EPEL.  Everything else with Graphite is working fine.  I'm even using Seyren to supplement it, and I'm having no problems sending emails from Seyren.  But I can't get Graphite to email the rendered graphs.

I've also tried using a gmail account:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And that doesn't work either.

I've also tried different Django backends.

**UPDATE**

Error being thrown by Graphite's e-mail feature:

```
"POST /dashboard/email HTTP/1.1" 500 5068
```

Other POST commands succeed:

```
"POST /metrics/find/ HTTP/1.1" 200 186
"POST /dashboard/find/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled over the same oddity, added Debug = True to **local_settings.py** and watched the output with Firebug. The file **graphite/dashboard/views.py** seems to break on line 365 with:

```
    target = QueryDict(graph_params.pop('target'))
```

The returned target is a list and QueryDict does **not** work on lists. I read something about QueryDict.lists() and QueryDict.dict() with Django 1.4+, but the rest of the code does not seem to expect a list of targets either. If you change the target to only use e.g. the first member of the target list then e-mailing works, but well... it's not a real fix at all.

```
target = QueryDict(graph_params.pop('target')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the e-mail problem. Now, however, no mater which ones I select, the graphs that are e-mailed are always blank white squares with the words "No Data" in red.